# Using equals in a select clause to set column aliases

Tags: sql, column-alias

Today I saw someone using this syntax (A) to set column aliases in a sql select.

## A

```
Select [ColumnAlias] = Column1 FROM Table
```

## B

Normally I use

```
Select Column1 AS [ColumnAlias] FROM Table
```

I've used `=` to set local variables, but never as aliases. `Select @LocalVar = Column1 FROM Table`

Is there any reason to prefer B over A? I can't seem to find much on A searching.

Comment: A is non-standard SQL and only supported by SQL Server as far as I know and won't work on other databases. Die-hard SQL Server fans prefer that over the ANSI compliant `AS ...` syntax. I prefer the standard way of defining a column alias

Comment: Most other DBMSs actually return an error, or , if `ColumnAlias` exists,  TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the two values are equal or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not many RDBMS support the *equals* syntax, but it is commonly used by VB/C# application developers who then learn MS SQL Server due to the similarity to assigning a value to a variable, that is certainly one way to look at it, and although I cannot find a reference, this syntax was probably adopted to encourage developers to adopt the MS SQL platform.

The problem is that this usage is ambiguous because the same syntax can be used to actually assign the value of a column into a variable, or in an `UPDATE` statement to assign the value into another column:

```
-- assign the variable the value from Column1
SELECT @MyVar = Column1 FROM Table

-- Update Column2 with the value from Column1
UPDATE Column2 = Column1 FROM Table
```

Using the `AS` keyword is supported in all SQL RDBMS, it is a lot less ambiguous as similar syntax only exists inside `CAST` functions.

### `AS` is more expressive, it is very clear what the intent is and cannot be mistaken to be an assignment.

Using `AS` is also considered more *standard* because the same syntax can be used to alias tables, views and other record sets in the SQL query.

> It is worth noting that `AS` is technically optional in most RDBMS, so you could leave it out altogether, but doing this can lead to other issues, especially if the alias you wanted to use actually exists as a real name of a column or a table. Reasons to use 'AS' are documented here: https://www.databasestar.com/sql-alias/

So while these variants will all work to alias a column in SQL Server:

```
SELECT Column1 AS [alias] from Table
SELECT Column1 AS 'alias' from Table
SELECT Column1 [alias] FROM Table
SELECT [alias] = Column1 FROM Table
```

Only `AS` (or omitting it) works for aliasing a table

```
SELECT Column1 AS [alias] from Table as t
SELECT Column1 [alias] FROM Table t
SELECT Column1 alias FROM Table [t]
```

The following will NOT work for table aliases
*Note here that we can't alias a table to a string value, it must be a **tokenized** name*

```
SELECT Column1 AS 'alias' from Table AS 't'
SELECT [alias] = Column1 FROM t = Table
```

Using `AS` is the most commonly supported syntax across all tables for *any* type of *alias* in a query, not just columns. For this reason you will find it as the most commonly documented syntax as well.